# How do I add additional files to a Chocolatey package?

Tags: git, powershell, nuget, chocolatey

I am installing a customized edition of the [`git.install`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install) package. I added some additional files in the `tools` directory.

```
git.install
  tools
    file1 
    file2
    chocolateyInstall.ps1
```

However, upon running `choco install git.install`, the files aren't found. I also checked the build directory in `chocolatey\lib-bad\git.install\tools` and found that the additional files were not copied.

Comment: Check the nuspec in the files section.

Comment: And once you have edited the files - you need to choco pack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding files, you need to check over the nuspec files section to ensure that the files will get included. Once you've verified that you need to then package everything back up into a nupkg (compiled version of the package, a fancy zip file).

Resources:

- https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages
- https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages#build-your-package
- https://blog.chocolatey.org/2016/01/create-chocolatey-packages/ - a recent write up I did.

Comment: Anyone know where that Puppetlabs article went?

Comment: Try here now - https://blog.chocolatey.org/2016/01/create-chocolatey-packages/

Comment: Fixed the post as well